# Custom Credential Provider Issue - Swift2.2 , AWS 2.4.9, AWSCredentials AWSCredentialsProvider

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, swift2

I am creating the custom credential provider so that I can set accesskey, secretkey, token and expiration. However I am receiving the below error while uploading the file

> [__NSCFString expiration]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Below is the Custom class I have created using Swift 2.2. How can I resolve this issue?

```
import AWSS3
import AWSCore.AWSCredentialsProvider
class MYAWSCredentialProvider:AWSCredentials, AWSCredentialsProvider{
var bucketName:String!
var token:String!
var awsAccessKey: String!
var awsSecretKey: String!
var awsExpiration: NSDate?
var awsRegion:String!

static let sharedInstance = MYAWSCredentialProvider(accessKey: "", secretKey: "", sessionKey: "")

@objc func logins() -> AWSTask {
    return AWSTask(result: token)
}

 init(accessKey: String, secretKey: String, sessionKey: String?) {
    super.init()
    self.token = sessionKey
    self.awsAccessKey = accessKey
    self.awsSecretKey = secretKey
}
private static func sharedInstanceWith(accessKey: String, secretKey: String, sessionKey: String) -> MYAWSCredentialProvider {
    let instance = MYAWSCredentialProvider.sharedInstance
    instance.token = sessionKey
    instance.awsAccessKey = accessKey
    instance.awsSecretKey = secretKey
    return instance
}
 func updateAWSInfo (jsonString: JSON) {
     awsAccessKey               = jsonString["accessKey"].stringValue
     awsSecretKey               = jsonString["secretKey"].stringValue
     bucketName                 = jsonString["bucketName"].stringValue
     awsRegion                     = jsonString["region"].stringValue
     token                      = jsonString["token"].stringValue
    let expirationTime         = jsonString["expirationTime"].stringValue
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E MMM d HH:mm:ss 'UTC' YYYY"////Fri Sep 30 14:42:53 UTC 2016
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(expirationTime)
    awsExpiration      =  date
    let credentialsProvider = MYAWSCredentialProvider.sharedInstanceWith(awsSecretKey, secretKey: awsSecretKey, sessionKey: token)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:AWSRegionType.APSoutheast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    configuration.maxRetryCount = 3;
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
}
@objc func credentials() -> AWSTask {
    return AWSTask(result: token)
}
 func invalidateCachedTemporaryCredentials(){

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your function with below.

```
@objc func credentials() -> AWSTask {

let credentials = AWSCredentials(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey, sessionKey: sessionKey, expiration: nil)

return AWSTask(result: credentials)

}
```